# Allowing relative paths only

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cordova, mod-rewrite, relative-path

I believe this is an Apache `.htaccess` issue, and yet, maybe not. Maybe I am looking at the problem from the wrong angle, and thus can't find the proper solution.

I am building a web app + hybrid mobile app. I would like to share the exact same code base, without having to tweak anything manually to deploy my app to Android or iOS, otherwise, the process of deploying will be hacky and painful. What I want is to take the web app repository, shove it into Cordova's **box** *(you dirty man ;)*, and it would deploy it successfully.

Now, one issue is that Cordova requires relative paths to work properly. For example, this is how I include my `require.js` file :

```
<script data-main="library/js/dependencies.js" src="library/js/libs/require.js">
</script>
```

This works fine on the hybrid app. This works fine also on most of the web app's URLs, those with the following scheme :

```
domain.com/view_name
```

However, this is what happens when I load the app from a view that receives URI parameters :

```
domain.com/view_name/6iwO4NyJqy
```

The relative paths are not resolved properly anymore. I get `404 error` due to unproper paths. For instance, this is how is resolved the `require.js` file above :

```
http://domain.com/view_name/library/js/libs/require.js
```

The `view_name` bit is the wrong part. It should not be there. Without it, the file would be found successfully.

This is my `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# REROUTING EVERYTHING TO index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [NC,L,QSA]
```

Is there a way to set my `.htaccess` file, so that I don't need to modify the relative paths within the app, and still can have them resolved properly ?

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: It is not caused by your rewrite rule, it is due to your use of relative paths. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: You rock dude. Thanks. I didn't know about this `<base/>` tag, thus could not formulate the solution properly. You should make this comment an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not caused by your rewrite rule, it is due to your use of relative paths.

You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.